# Why is my FoxyCart Datafeed getting a different POST than it should?

Tags: module

When comparing FoxyCart's Transaction Datafeed's raw POSTs to any other web service, EE's reception seems totally different.

What is going on?

I am using the latest version of EE as of this writing, 2.8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_REQUEST` because it remains untouched.

FTR it's not the `permitted_uri_chars` config item. The `$_POST` and `ee()->input->post(...)` are cleaned via `Input::_clean_input_data`.

Instead of hacking core (which is an option, see below) I got the hint to use `$_REQUEST` from this CI issue:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1136